# Rapid decay times polynomial decay is L^1?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

I have a smooth function $f(x)$ which is of rapid decay (actually I know it's a Schwartz function), and I have another function $g(x)$ which behaves like a polynomial as $x \to \pm \infty$; that is
$$ \lim_{|x| \to \infty} |g(x)| = \lim_{|x| \to \infty} |x|^c $$
for some constant $c$.  Is it true that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)||g(x)| dx < \infty; $$
that is, is $fg \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

My feeling is that the rapid decay of $f$ and the fact that $g$ behaves like a polynomial should guarantee the $L^1$-convergence, but I'm having trouble proving this fact.

Comment: Multiplying an $L^1$ function (in this case $f$) with a bounded function ($g$) will always give you another $L^1$ function.

Comment: I don't have that $g(x)$ is bounded though.  All I know is that it behaves like $x^c$ near $\pm \infty$.

Comment: (Polynomials don't decay, they grow.)

Comment: Thanks. I changed "decay" to "behaves" so hopefully this is more clear now.

Comment: You need at least $g \in L^1$, though, otherwise there is no reason for the product to be in $L^1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am interpreting your statement "decays like a polynomial" to mean something a bit different than what you wrote ($|x|^c$ goes to infinity with $x$ when $c > 0$, but I don't think you just meant that $g$ blows up at infinity), instead that there exists $M$ such that for $|x| \geq M$ $g(x) \leq C|x|^c$ for some $C, c$.  Does that capture your intention?

I think in this case for the tail integrals you could estimate
$$\int_M^{\infty}|fg| \, dx \leq C \int_M^{\infty} |f||x|^c = C \int_M^{\infty} |f| |x|^{c+2} \frac{1}{x^2} \leq C \sup{|fx^{c+2}|}\int_M^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}$$

And now use the rapid decrease of $f$ to conclude this quantity is finite.  Of course using an exponent of $2$ here is not critical, you could use any integrable exponent.

Comment: Yes, I think I can show $g(x)$ is $O(|x|^c)$ and estimate the tails as you suggested.  Thanks!